# Clear Userform Checkboxes after CopyPaste VBA

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I am new to programming (so please be patient) and was trying to develop a code that involves userform checkboxes. I want to populate a list that uses checkboxes for each month. During the new month, the user would click the macro button to insert a new month. However, I would need the checkboxes to reset for the new month, while keeping previous months intact. I understand how to insert the column with the new month but I can't figure out how to reset the checkboxes. Any suggestions? My code is below:

```
Sub new_month()

Range("B:B").Select
Range("B3:B16").Copy
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range("b3: b16 ").Select
Selection.CheckBoxes.Value = 0

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This relies on your checkboxes aligning with one column wide and one row tall. It also assumes you are copying entire columns. I'm sure it won't work perfectly, but it's a start, I hope:

```
Sub new_month()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim shp As Shape
Dim LastCol As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet
With ws
    LastCol = .Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    .Columns(LastCol).Copy
    .Columns(LastCol).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    For Each shp In ws.Shapes
        If shp.TopLeftCell.Column = LastCol + 1 Then
            shp.ControlFormat.Value = False
        End If
    Next shp
End With
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT**: This inserts the new row at the left. It's simpler, since there's no need to calculate the last column:

```
Sub new_month()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim shp As Shape

Set ws = ActiveSheet
With ws
    .Columns(1).Copy
    .Columns(1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    For Each shp In ws.Shapes
        If shp.TopLeftCell.Column = 1 Then
            shp.ControlFormat.Value = False
        End If
    Next shp
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks much! This works almost exactly the way I want it to but how can I get the most recent column to insert to the left of the old data? i.e. apr...mar...feb...jan

Answer (score 0):

If you have prepared the CheckBoxes nicely (Name them appropriately), then you can Clear/Tick the checkboxes with ease. If you Add reference "Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library" to VBE, you can see properties you can check/change.

This macro below will list some properties of the checkbox including Name, Text, and state of the Value:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ClearCheckBoxes()
    Dim oWS As Worksheet, oCB As CheckBox
    Set oWS = ActiveSheet
    For Each oCB In oWS.CheckBoxes
        With oCB
            Debug.Print "=== CheckBox Properties ==="
            Debug.Print "Name: " & .Name
            Debug.Print "Text: " & .Text
            Debug.Print "Value: " & .Value
            Debug.Print "TopLeftCell: " & .TopLeftCell.Address
            Debug.Print "BottomRightCell: " & .BottomRightCell.Address
            Debug.Print "Top: " & .Top
            Debug.Print "TopLeftCell.Top: " & .TopLeftCell.Top
            Debug.Print "Left: " & .Left
            Debug.Print "Height: " & .Height
            Debug.Print "Width: " & .Width
            Debug.Print "LinkedCell: " & .LinkedCell
            Debug.Print "ShapeRange.Name: " & .ShapeRange.Name ' <-- You can use Shapes collection from Worksheet to reference
        End With
        'oCB.Value = False ' Clears the checkbox
        'oCB.Value = True ' Ticks the checkbox
        Debug.Print ""
    Next
End Sub
```